# Fetching website html using python

Tags: python, request, lxml

I am very new to Python. I had a working code to get an html page and parse text from it but it stopped working recently. Perhaps the website changed,but I am not able to retrieve the data anymore.

Any help is appreciated. Here is the code that used to work before.

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor
from lxml import etree

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36'
url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/markets/stocks/symbol-change-history.aspx?sortby=EFFECTIVE&d'
cj = CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', user_agent),('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]

page = opener.open(url, timeout=2)
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
rootDOM = etree.parse(page, parser)  
html = etree.tostring(rootDOM.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method='html')
```

I get error SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)

Comment: Try increasing your `timeout=2` value on this line `page = opener.open(url, timeout=2)` to `timeout=30`.

Comment: No luck with even 60 seconds timeout